# Insert a node in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

The teacher gave us this code that inserts a node in a binary search tree, but I am not sure what the $z.p = y$ instruction does. wouldn't the algorithm work without it?

```
abr_insert(T, z) //z is the node that must be inserted
    {
            y = NULL;
            x = T.root;
            while(x != NULL)
            {
                    y  = x;
                    if(z.key < x.key)
                            x = x.left;
                    else
                            x = x.right;
            }
            z.p = y; //here is the instruction that I don't understand
            if(y = NULL)
                T.root = z;
            else if(z.key < y,key)
                    y.left = z;
            else
                    y.right = z;
    }
```

Comment: The insert algorithm may not use `z.p`, but it is possible that another BST method relies on the existence and correctness of the value of `z.p`. It look like `z.p` stores a pointer to the parent of the node that is to be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this algorithm is keeping track of parent pointers. Each node `N` has three fields: `N.left` (left child), `N.right` (right child), and `N.p` (parent). The variable `y` is used to keep track of the most recent parent, so when we fall off the tree (i.e. when `x == NULL`) we can use `y` as the parent of the new node `z`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this particular method doesn't use the y.parent pointer. However, other methods rely on it. Consider finding `successor`:

1. Traverse to the right if x.right is present to find smallest key greater than x.key
2. If the right subtree of node x is empty and x has a successor y, then y is the lowest `ancestor` of x whose left child is also an ancestor of x

Python code:

```
def successor(self, x: Node):
    if x.right:
        return self.min(x.right) # traverse the right subtree to get a min
    y = x.parent
    while y and x == y.parent: # go "down" the tree using y.parent
        x = y
        y = y.parent
    return y
```